# In UITableViewController template missing TableViewCell allocation

Tags: ios, uitableview

Recently I noticed that when we creates a new Class template, (Xcode -> File -> New -> File) which is a subclass of UITableViewController implementation is partial in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. I pasted the method below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   // Configure the cell...

   return cell;
}
```

I think statements like (which is missing),

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

is must in implementation. Is this a bug or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a cell if you are registering a cell in your table view with the method `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or creating a cell within your table view in a xib or storyboard.